# Ask user if they want to play again or not, c#

Tags: c#, menu, console-application

I am new to C# and am programming a game menu that plays 3 different games, but at the end of each game, I want to ask the user if they would like to play again.  Below I provided my menu and one of the three games, how would I replay the game if the user wants to play again, and return to menu if the user does not want to?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Menu();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    static void Menu() 
    {
        int userChoice = MenuChoice();

        if (userChoice == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you, Goodbye!");
        }

        while (userChoice != 4)
        {
            if (userChoice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Slot Machine!\n");
                 SlotMachineGame();
            }
            if (userChoice == 2)
                    {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Dice!");
                 DiceGame();
            }
            if (userChoice == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Roulette Wheel!\n");
                RouletteWheel();
            }
            userChoice = MenuChoice();
        }

            }
    static int MenuChoice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Jolly Jackpot Land!");
        Console.WriteLine("You can play our two traditional games: Slot Machine and Dice.");
        Console.WriteLine("Or.. Try the all new Roulette Wheel!");
        Console.WriteLine("Further rules for each game will be displayed when chosen.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 to play Slot Machine");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 2 to play Dice");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 3 to play Roulette Wheel");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 4 to Exit");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");

        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        while (!(choice == "1" || choice == "2" || choice == "3"))
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Please try again");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to play Slot Machine");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 2 to play Dice");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 3 to exit");

            choice = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return int.Parse(choice);
    }

    static void SlotMachineGame()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The objective of this game is to match words. Rewards listed below:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("No words match: Lose the Gil you risked");
        Console.WriteLine("Two words match: win DOUBLE the amount of Gil risked");
        Console.WriteLine("Three words match: win TRIPLE the amount of Gil risked\n");
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<string> list = new List<string> { "Elephant", "Computer", "Football", "Resume", "Capstone", "Crimson" }; // List of words being randomly chosen
        List<string> wordsChosen = new List<string>(); // storing three random words here

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of Gil you would like to risk: "); // Asking user bet amount and storing bet amount and potential winnings
        double gil = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double winningAmountSlot = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
            string word = list[rand.Next(list.Count)];
            wordsChosen.Add(word);
            Console.Write(word + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        if (wordsChosen[0] == wordsChosen[1] && wordsChosen[1] == wordsChosen[2])
            {
            winningAmountSlot = gil * 3;
        }

        else if (wordsChosen[0] == wordsChosen[1] || wordsChosen[0] == wordsChosen[2] || wordsChosen[1] == wordsChosen[2])
        {
            winningAmountSlot = gil * 2;
        }
        else 
            {
            winningAmountSlot = 0;
        }
        Console.Write("You won: " + winningAmountSlot + " Gil from playing Slot Machine\n");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean, play the game they just played ?

Comment: Yes, so at the end of the slot machine game, it would ask the user if they would like to play again, if yes the same game is replayed, if no, the program returns to the menu of other games.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `Action` and a loop, I'll leave the details up to you:

**Given**

```
public static void PlayAgain(Action action)
{
   do
   {
      action();
      Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? y/n");
   } while (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y);
}
```

**Usage**

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Slot Machine!\n");
PlayAgain(SlotMachineGame);
```